# Props in vue (3): Template fetches props value directly without reference to props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-props

Given this following Vue3 sfc code:

```
<template>
    <div>{{msg}}</div>
</template>

<script setup>
    const props = defineProps({
        msg: {
            type: String,
            default: 'Hello world'
        }
    })
</script>
```

How/why is it that the props value `props.msg` can directly be referred to from the template tag, without me having to write `<div>{{props.msg}}</div>` and what is this called?

Any documentation on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options passed to `defineProps` (in your case `msg`) will be hoisted out of setup into module scope. You cannot reference local variables declared in setup scope (in your case `props`). More [here](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits)

Comment: Can we use: **<div>{{this.msg}}</div>**, does that work?